# Matrix Multiplication using divide and conquer in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I wrote a program in python3 to find out a product of 2 `n*n` matrices, (*where* `n` *is a power of 2*).

Why the code below does not work out and shows `IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable`?

```
import numpy as np

def product(x, y, k):
    def fsum(p, q, m):
        r = [[p[i, j] + q[i, j] for j in range(m)] for i in range(m)]
        return r

    if k == 1:
        return x[0][0] * y[0][0]
    else:
        A = x[0:(k // 2), 0:(k // 2)]
        B = x[0:(k // 2), (k // 2):k]
        C = x[(k // 2):k, 0:(k // 2)]
        D = x[(k // 2):k, (k // 2):k]

        E = y[0:(k // 2), 0:(k // 2)]
        F = y[0:(k // 2), (k // 2):k]
        G = y[(k // 2):k, 0:(k // 2)]
        H = y[(k // 2):k, (k // 2):k]

        C00 = fsum(product(A, E, k // 2), product(B, G, k // 2), k // 2)
        C01 = fsum(product(A, F, k // 2), product(B, H, k // 2), k // 2)
        C10 = fsum(product(C, E, k // 2), product(D, G, k // 2), k // 2)
        C11 = fsum(product(C, F, k // 2), product(D, H, k // 2), k // 2)

        return np.array([[C00, C01], [C10, C11]])

n = int(input('Enter index(power of 2): '))
print('Input 1st matrix')
a = np.array([[int(_) for _ in input().split()] for x in range(n)])
print('Input 2nd matrix')
b = np.array([[int(_) for _ in input().split()] for x in range(n)])
print(product(a, b, n))
```

Comment: Please provide some example data and drop that `input()` nonsense

Comment: Why the need for `fsum(p, q, m)`? What's wrong with `p+q`?

Comment: It would be useful if you specify the line with error and explain what are you trying to do using the code

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way of doing it:

```
def product(X, Y):
    k = len(X)
    if k == 1:
        return X * Y
    (A, B), (C, D) = skimage.util.view_as_blocks(X, block_shape=(k // 2, k // 2))
    (E, F), (G, H) = skimage.util.view_as_blocks(Y, block_shape=(k // 2, k // 2))

    out = np.zeros((k, k))
    (I, J), (K, L) = skimage.util.view_as_blocks(out, block_shape=(k // 2, k // 2))
    I[:] = product(A, E) + product(B, G)
    J[:] = product(A, F) + product(B, H)
    K[:] = product(C, E) + product(D, G)
    L[:] = product(C, F) + product(D, H)
    return out
```

Needless to say it is terribly slow

```
A = numpy.random.rand(32, 32)

np.allclose(product(A, A), A @ A)
# True
%timeit product(A, A)
# 526 ms ± 11.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit A @ A
# 4.36 µs ± 59.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comment: Good work. I couldn't understand from the code what OP wanted to achieve since `fsum` needs input matrices but gets integers

Answer (score 0):

A sample run:

```
Enter index(power of 2): 2
Input 1st matrix
1 2
3 4
[[1 2]
 [3 4]]
Input 2nd matrix
3 4
5 6
[[3 4]
 [5 6]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stack51061196.py", line 35, in <module>
    print(product(a, b, n))
  File "stack51061196.py", line 21, in product
    C00 = fsum(product(A, E, k // 2), product(B, G, k // 2), k // 2)
  File "stack51061196.py", line 5, in fsum
    r = [[p[i, j] + q[i, j] for j in range(m)] for i in range(m)]
  File "stack51061196.py", line 5, in <listcomp>
    r = [[p[i, j] + q[i, j] for j in range(m)] for i in range(m)]
  File "stack51061196.py", line 5, in <listcomp>
    r = [[p[i, j] + q[i, j] for j in range(m)] for i in range(m)]
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

Adding a `print('p,q', p, q, type(p), type(q))` to the `fsum` I see

```
p,q 1 6 <class 'numpy.int64'> <class 'numpy.int64'>
```

So `p` is a `np.int64` object, not an array.  It's already been indexed, and can't go any further.

```
In [193]: x = np.array([1])[0]
In [194]: x
Out[194]: 1
In [195]: type(x)
Out[195]: numpy.int64
In [196]: x[0,0]
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

Another diagnostic print

```
print('product AE',k,type(product(A, E, k // 2)))
```

displays

```
product AE 2 <class 'numpy.int64'>
```

So when `k` is 2, `product` returns a `scalar variable`, an `int64` object, not an array.  Passing that to `fsum` produces the error.

It's this branch of the `product` that causes the problem - `x[0][0]` (why not `x[0,0]`?) is an element of `x`:

```
if k == 1:
    return x[0][0] * y[0][0]
```

At this point `x` is (1,1) shape, so you could just write

```
if k == 1:
     return x * y
```

With this change I get:

```
0840:~/mypy$ python3 stack51061196.py 
a,b [[1 2]
 [3 4]] [[1 2]
 [3 4]]
A [[1]] <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
product AE 2 <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
p,q [[1]] [[6]] <class 'numpy.ndarray'> <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
p,q [[2]] [[8]] <class 'numpy.ndarray'> <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
p,q [[3]] [[12]] <class 'numpy.ndarray'> <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
p,q [[6]] [[16]] <class 'numpy.ndarray'> <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
[[[[ 7]]

  [[10]]]


 [[[15]]

  [[22]]]]
```

which apart from dimensions matches:

```
In [197]: a=np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
In [198]: np.dot(a,a)
Out[198]: 
array([[ 7, 10],
       [15, 22]])
```

Your shape is `(2, 2, 1, 1)`, which can be removed with `squeeze`, but you really should refine the iteration to get the shape right without it.

It also gets the right numbers for a 4x4 array, but the shape is now `(2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1)`.